# I have a problem with my navbar. I am using React and I have an issue when changing state, my navbar is getting bigger. I am using TailwindCSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, navbar

I have a light and dark mode. When in light mode, the toggle button is below the navbar, as expected but when I switch to dark mode, my navbar gets bigger and now the toggle button is in it. I want the button to be below the navbar whether or not in light or dark mode, and I want the navbar to stay the same size.

[Light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrip6.png)
[Dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r0P8.png)

Notice how the navbar got bigger, and the toggle button moved into it?

My navbar component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Navbar({ toggleTheme }) {
    return (
        <header className="bg-gray-800 md:sticky top-0 z-10 reset navbar" style={{ height: '60px' }}>
            <div className="container mx-auto p-5 text-center md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:items-center">
                <div className="col-span-2 flex flex-col md:flex-row md:items-center md:text-left">
                    <a className="title-font font-medium text-white mb-4 md:mb-0" style={{ lineHeight: '1.5' }}>
                        <a href="#about" className="ml-3 text-xl" style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>
                            My Name
                        </a>
                    </a>
                    <nav className="md:ml-10 md:py-1 md:pl-4 md:border-l md:border-gray-700 flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center md:justify-start text-base">
                        <a href="#projects" className="mr-5 hover:text-white">
                            Past Work
                        </a>
                        <a href="#skills" className="mr-5 hover:text-white">
                            Skills
                        </a>
                        <a href="#contact" className="mr-5 hover:text-white">
                            Contact
                        </a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}
```

My ToggleButton component:

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from '../ThemeContext';

export default function LightDarkModeToggle({ toggleTheme }) {
    const { themeMode } = React.useContext(ThemeContext);

    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto p-5 flex items-center justify-end">
            <div className="flex items-center ml-2">
                <span className={`text-sm font-medium ${themeMode === 'light' ? 'text-black' : 'text-white'}`}>
                    Light
                </span>
                <label className="relative inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer ml-2">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        value=""
                        className="sr-only peer"
                        onChange={toggleTheme}
                    />
                    <div
                        className={`w-9 h-5 ${themeMode === 'light' ? 'bg-yellow-600' : 'bg-green-500'} bg-gray-200 peer-focus:outline-none peer-focus:ring-4 peer-focus:ring-blue-300 ${themeMode === 'light' ? 'dark:peer-focus:ring-yellow-600' : 'dark:peer-focus:ring-green-500'} rounded-full peer dark:white peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-[2px] after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-4 after:w-4 after:transition-all dark:border-gray-600 ${themeMode === 'light' ? 'peer-checked:bg-yellow-600' : 'peer-checked:bg-green-500'}`}
                    />
                    <span className={`ml-2 text-sm font-medium ${themeMode === 'light' ? 'text-black' : 'text-white'}`}>
                        Dark
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Before I had the toggle button in the Navbar component but decided to move it below it and had this issue since. I also tried to create a CSS file but it did not make any change:

```
.toggle-container {
  height: 60px;
}
```

Here's my App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import classnames from "classnames";
import LightDarkModeToggle from "./components/LightDarkToggle";
import About from "./components/About";
import Skills from "./components/Skills";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Projects from "./components/Projects";
import ScrollButton from "./components/ScrollButton";
import { ThemeContext } from "./ThemeContext";

function App() {
  const [themeMode, setThemeMode] = useState("light");

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setThemeMode((prevMode) => (prevMode === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
  };

  const themeClass = classnames({
    "bg-neutral-200": themeMode === "light",
    "bg-gray-800": themeMode === "dark",
    "text-black": themeMode === "light",
    "text-white": themeMode === "dark",
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{ mode: themeMode }}>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ themeMode, toggleTheme }}>
        <div className={`text-gray-400 body-font ${themeClass}`}>
          <Navbar />
          <br />
          <LightDarkModeToggle toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
          <About />
          <Projects />
          <Skills />
          <Contact />
          <ScrollButton />
        </div>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can provide some screenshots and also the code where you're using the Navbar and Toggle components.

Comment: It could be because you're using the same bg-color in div and navbar in app.js. toggle component and the navbar share the same background from parent div so you can try setting a different background to toggle component that may help.